# Lotus Notes - @FileDir command

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am using a script ( created in lotusscript ) and I want to get the path of a file. Is there a solution in lotusscript for command @FileDir?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact command, but this should solve it.

```
Dim x as String
x = StrLeftBack("c:\notes\data\test.nsf", "\")
print x
```

More details on the command here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_STRLEFTBACK.html

To get just the filename.

```
Const filename = "c:\notes\data\test.nsf"

Dim x as String
x = StrLeftBack(filename, "\")
if x <> "" then x = StrRight(filename,x + "\")
print x
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I want the path of a file which I select from a browse-option. For this, is there any solution?

Comment: Please: Your Questions are all so unprecise and do not show ANY efford in investigation. They all seem to be like "please be my personal google". Questions like this make people ignore you. So for your own sake: Show at least a LITTLE efford to solve your questions by yourself.

Comment: Thank you, Torsten, for your advice!

Comment: Thank you! Even if my question wasn't clear enough, it will help me. I have the filename stored in a variable. The file was selected from a command like @Command([EditGotoField] ; "rtfAttachment" ); @Command( [EditInsertFileAttachment] );. So, I was wondering how could I find the path also, not only the filename.

Answer (score 1):

I posted some code last year to do file operations, including extracting path name.
http://blog.texasswede.com/code-expanded-class-for-file-functions/

Comment: Your one is certainly the answer + kitchen sink. V.Nice. :)

Comment: Thank you for your great infos! But, is there any chance to get the path ( in Lotus ) if I only have the file name?

Comment: @MFGFlay, how do you imagine this? Of course you could try to scan all folders on all your disks (very time consuming operation), but you could find many files with the same name. What path do you want to get in this case?

Comment: I see. Thanks! The blog above is a very helpfully tool! Thanks again!

Comment: Well, there may be many files with the same name, but in Win at Properties - Location, the Location is different. I was wondering if I can get the Location (Path) having only the file name. : - ) Thanks for your time!

Comment: No, how do you imagine you would be able to get the path if you just have a file name? As pstr writes above, in order to do that you need to write a recursive function that goes through the file system, then you have the path for each file. If you look at Properties/Location in Windows, the path is not stored in the file itself, it is Windows Explorer that keep track of where you are.